# Function which updates an array and returns a map

Tags: typescript

```
export const updateWatchlist = (coin: IAsset, watchlist: IAsset[]) => {
  watchlist.push(coin)
  return watchlist.map((c) => c)
}
```

Is this 1-line-able with a lib like [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write

```
export const updateWatchlist = (coin: IAsset, list: IAsset[]) => [...list, coin];
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out :D

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat

```
export const updateWatchlist = (coin: IAsset, watchlist: IAsset[]) => R.concat(watchlist, [coin]);
```

Comment: You don't need a library [to use concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)